# Case Send Email Quick Action

Tags: service-cloud-console

Is there a reason I am unable to see the default Send Email Quick Action on my Case Feed, or any custom Email Quick Action... I have email-to-case turned on and deliverability is set to All Emails.  What small checkbox somewhere am I missing?

Page Layout Editor:
[image]

Saved Page Layout, Feed View:
[image]

**So question--- What is the difference between Send Email and Email?  Why does Send Email not work?**

Comment: Is there a publisher or global layout for this .I am sure you are missing to configure these .I am not near computer but i would definately check page layouts and publisher actions

Comment: I'm using the standard quick action - updating my post to include images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was the "Email" quick action was not configured on the page layout of the user .Only those actions appear which are dragged on quick action area.

Send Email - This is very specific to Salesforce 1 .If you enable this your Salesforce 1 has Send Email publisher .This will be visible only on the Salesforce 1 Mobile app and hence you may not see any change once you look at desktop view.Here is the [reference](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=actions_overview.htm)

Email - This is for service cloud layout and this was missing.

Comment: Is there any way to add custom Send Email quick action to the Service Console publisher? I'm wanting to use a custom action that pre-populates CC with values from the Case.

Comment: @DougAyers Would you mind posting a new query with some nice details and screenshot :) .Thank you